# BouncyCastleProvider not found by JAR on Lucee

Tags: java, coldfusion, bouncycastle, apache-felix, lucee

We are successfully using the AmazonPay API for Java (`amazon-pay-api-sdk-java-2.2.2.jar`) in Adobe ColdFusion. We recently introduced Lucee (on Jetty, also running on OpenJDK 8) and attempted to run the same code (relevant excerpt):

```
payConfig = createObject("java", "com.amazon.pay.api.PayConfiguration").init();
payConfig.setPrivateKey("...");
```

However, upon calling `setPrivateKey`, which will arrive at [`Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());`](https://github.com/amzn/amazon-pay-api-sdk-java/blob/83f0fa13d4bae50218e94d010ff9360823a8616b/src/com/amazon/pay/api/Util.java#L150) through `PayConfiguration`, we receive a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`:

```
lucee.runtime.exp.NativeException: org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
  at com.amazon.pay.api.PayConfiguration.setPrivateKey(PayConfiguration.java:77)
  [...]
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:823)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
  ... 57 more
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider not found by amazon.pay.api.sdk.java.2.2.2 [49]
  at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1597)
  at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$300(BundleWiringImpl.java:79)
  at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1982)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:881)
  ... 57 more
```

We have placed all dependencies (`bcprov-jdk15on-1.65.jar` being BouncyCastle) in `/lucee-server/context/lib`. Creating `BouncyCastleProvider` within a .cfm/.cfc does work as expected:
`createObject("java", "org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider").init()`

I don't understand what Lucee's classloader is doing here. What am I missing?

Comment: I can't find a version 2.2.2 of Amazon's jar on their Github repo or on mvn. The current version is 3.6.5 and that *seems* to work with Lucee (from a very quick test).

Comment: Which versions of Lucee and ColdFusion are you using?

Comment: @CfSimplicity [Release on GitHub](https://github.com/amzn/amazon-pay-api-sdk-java/releases/tag/2.2.2) or [on Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/software.amazon.pay/amazon-pay-api-sdk-java/2.2.2). I tried Lucee version `5.3.7.47` and `5.3.8.139-RC`. The version you mention is the "old" Amazon Pay API v1.

Comment: Ah, apologies. I just searched for "amazon pay java" and that's what came up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know what Lucee's classloader is doing either to be honest, but this kind of error seems to be quite common when loading certain more complex jars via the Lucee `/lib` path. It's likely there are "class clashes" going on somewhere.

Lucee is now OSGi based which means the best way of avoiding this is to load third-party java libraries as OSGi bundles. Some libraries are already packaged for OSGi and others can be converted fairly easily. [More details here](https://blog.simplicityweb.co.uk/121/loading-java-libraries-dynamically-in-lucee-without-javaloader).

The Amazon library doesn't seem to be OSGi friendly, although it could probably be converted without too much effort.

For now, I would look at [JavaLoader](https://github.com/markmandel/JavaLoader/wiki/Class-Loading) as the simplest way of getting it working. I don't have any valid Amazon keys to test fully with, but using JavaLoader I was able to at least call the `payConfig.setPrivateKey()` method without getting a `ClassNotFoundException` error.

Comment: Very interesting blog article. That helped me understanding the issue a bit more. I ended up modifying the `MANIFEST.MF` in the Amazon Pay JAR with `Class-Path: bcprov-jdk15on-1.68.jar commons-beanutils-1.9.4.jar commons-collections-3.2.2.jar ezmorph-1.0.6.jar json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar` and putting mentioned dependencies in Lucee's `lib` folder. Everything works now in Lucee and it also works on ColdFusion server. It's not an elegant solution though. Compiling the source and target bundle is probably the correct solution for Lucee.

Comment: Glad you got it working, although I'm just wary of loading via the `lib` path. For me the solution that feels "correct" for Lucee is the OSGi bundle approach, which you could also do by packaging the dependencies and modifying the MANIFEST.MF. For ACF cross-compat, JavaLoader would my preference.

Comment: Update: I ended up downgrading BouncyCastle to the version that is shipped with ColdFusion10 (adjusted Amazon source code and recompiled). There was just no reliable way to make it work for both CFML engines as it broke again with an older version of Lucee. It's still a horrible solution. :(

Comment: Did you try JavaLoader?

Comment: I did first, but that also caused trouble with the most recent version of BouncyCastle.

Comment: Strange. As I said, I was able to call `payConfig.setPrivateKey()` using the Amazon jar via JavaLoader without getting the classNotFoundException. But I can't test fully without valid creds, and getting some involves jumping through too many hoops.

Comment: Well yeah, you've reached the point where `PemReader` and `PemObject` are successfully loaded, but then it fails at the JCE part. I tried adding BC explicitly via `Security.addProvider()`, but to no avail.