# Amazon Pay - Signing requests using Coldfusion

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, coldfusion, amazon-pay

I'm trying Amazon pay API using Coldfusion. In the authorization, I'm continuously getting the "InvalidRequestSignature" error. I've followed every step given in this [document](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/amazon-pay-api-v2/signing-requests.html) correctly.

I can run this successfully in the node SDK. I've got the x-amz-pay-date and x-amz-pay-idempotency-key from that response and checked in the ColdFusion by giving those statically for those headers. The string generated in ColdFusion is same as the string generated in node SDK like this: `AMZN-PAY-RSASSA-PSS\nfb972741819aa4124204361d8bf6524b83aca4bc7e2313c4c9da5111dea8743c`

I don't know what is happening on the ColdFusion.

This is my canonical request string

```
POST
/v2/checkoutSessions

accept:application/json
content-type:application/json
x-amz-pay-date:2021-09-23T16:28:54Z
x-amz-pay-host:pay-api.amazon.eu
x-amz-pay-idempotency-key:c2e281a1f01c63529d67b838e4bfcffd
x-amz-pay-region:uk

accept;content-type;x-amz-pay-date;x-amz-pay-host;x-amz-pay-idempotency-key;x-amz-pay-region
fa427e08f2b6e529b67275f6e9210101b5538252c42f4f4c7408aafda5050043
```

FYI, if you see this in ColdFusion, you can not see the line break.

This is my StringToSign:

```
AMZN-PAY-RSASSA-PSS\nfb972741819aa4124204361d8bf6524b83aca4bc7e2313c4c9da5111dea8743c
```

This is my error:

```
{"reasonCode":"InvalidRequestSignature","message":"Unable to verify signature, signing String [AMZN-PAY-RSASSA-PSS\nc9a4938f623a2904fdea51cg07cd6e6b20ff350c80f20445ba3d5a89fc4077eb] , signature [o7QA2WUEzE6qy7giGirM62LuhxgjFPuzf1+oCnJSgMOTltotF5Gxp2t/oWtms+9myFtsSvT6N0ZNViUckFL3XUPjvDF8QTH+dWKugL2h8147MAN9yt2wORgGYExEk+oqNeUmfMhz0AXZu+wdRsKHs97AbDrMmj9lAbM0Orh5p2xvBVFf5PMYhpSe0a50i7QL+GYSipwNmAXEQOualpkpnVjk6lXhewSMyef2p0XZxnJDE1cyr6iBtWSwCBn4gk17yQGmifJb8joPgYEh3BPQLmHTXOSubJSYxEJZcHYYG35DPIIFqyJEQsJGRlfkVLaS27xjHpzZOTNgyZLMuS1jXQ==]"}
```

I'm not sure whether I'm making a mistake in the RSA-SHA256 encryption algorithm or not. I'm following [Ben Nadel's RSA-Encrypted Signature Generation](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2941-experimenting-with-rsa-encrypted-signature-generation-and-verification-in-coldfusion.htm).

I can not find any solution for ColdFusion. That's why I asked here. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
<cffunction name="createCanonicalRequest" access="private" returnType="string">
    <cfargument name="requestMethod" type="string" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="originalURI" type="string" required="true" />
    <cfargument name="queryParams" type="struct" required="false" default={} />
    <cfargument name="requestHeaders" type="struct" required="false" default={} />
    <cfargument name="requestPayload" type="string" required="false" default="" />

    <cfset var canonicalRequestMethod = arguments.requestMethod>

    
    <cfset var trimmedURI = len(trim(originalURI)) ? originalURI : "/" & originalURI>
    <cfset var canonicalURI = replace( encodeRFC3986( trimmedURI ), "%2F", "/", "all")>

    
    <cfset var encodedParams = {}>
    <cfscript>
        structEach( queryParams, function(key, value) {
            encodedParams[ encodeRFC3986(arguments.key) ] = encodeRFC3986( arguments.value);
        });
    </cfscript>
    <cfset var encodedKeyNames = structKeyArray( encodedParams )>
    <cfset arraySort( encodedKeyNames, "text" )>
    
    <cfset var encodedPairs  = []>
    <cfscript>
        for (var key in encodedKeyNames) {
            arrayAppend( encodedPairs, key &"="& encodedParams[ key ] );
        }
    </cfscript>
    
    <cfset var canonicalQueryString = arrayToList( encodedPairs, "&")>

    
    <cfset var cleanedHeaders = {}>
    <cfscript>
        structEach( requestHeaders, function(key, value) {
            var headerName = reReplace( trim(arguments.key), "\s+", " ", "all");
            var headerValue = reReplace( trim(arguments.value), "\s+", " ", "all");
            cleanedHeaders[ lcase(headerName) ] = headerValue;
        });
    </cfscript>
    
    <cfset var sortedHeaderNames = structKeyArray( cleanedHeaders )>
    <cfset arraySort( sortedHeaderNames, "text" )>
    
    <cfset var cleanedPairs  = []>
    <cfscript>
        for (var key in sortedHeaderNames) {
            arrayAppend( cleanedPairs, key &":"& cleanedHeaders[ key ] );
        }
    </cfscript>
    
    <cfset var canonicalHeaderString = arrayToList( cleanedPairs, Chr(10) ) & Chr(10)>

    
    <cfset var canonicalSignedHeaderString = arrayToList( sortedHeaderNames, ";" )>

    
    <cfset var canonicalPayloadChecksum = lcase( hash( requestPayload , "SHA256", "UTF-8" ) )>

    
    <cfset var canonicalRequest = canonicalRequestMethod & Chr(10)
                & canonicalURI & Chr(10)
                & canonicalQueryString & Chr(10)
                & canonicalHeaderString & Chr(10)
                & canonicalSignedHeaderString & Chr(10)
                & canonicalPayloadChecksum>

    <cfset var requestDigest = lcase( hash( canonicalRequest , "SHA256", "UTF-8" ) )>

    <cfreturn variables.amazonSignatureAlgorithm & Chr(10) & requestDigest />
</cffunction>
```

---

```
<cffunction name="encodeRFC3986" access="private" returnType="string">
    <cfargument name="text" type="string" required="true" />

    <cfset var encoded = encodeForURL(arguments.text)>
    <cfset encoded = replace( encoded, "%7E", "~", "all" )>
    <cfset encoded = replace( encoded, "+", "%20", "all" )>
    <cfset encoded = replace( encoded, "*", "%2A", "all" )>

    <cfreturn encoded />
</cffunction>
```

I'm using the above UDF to create the canonical request.
FYI, I'm using Coldfusion 2016.

Comment: You are not showing any code. How are you building the string to sign in CF? Anyway, [consider using the Amazon Pay SDK for Java](https://github.com/amzn/amazon-pay-api-sdk-java) instead (works perfectly fine with ACF, it's [a bit troublesome with Lucee though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66037089/bouncycastleprovider-not-found-by-jar-on-lucee)). It will save you a lot of time.

Comment: If you are using the literal string `\n` in your CF code, it doesn't work in CF. (Though it does in java). For a new line use `chr(10)`.

Comment: @Alex, I've added the function to build the string to sign above. I don't want to use any SDK. Thanks.

Comment: @SOS, I'm using chr(10) only.

Comment: I've also worked on this using node SDK. The string to sign generating in both ACF and node js is the same. I don't know whether I'm making mistakes in creating signature. or not. I'm using code from Ben Nadel's RSA encryption

Comment: Your stringToSign contains "\n", not chr(10)

Comment: @Alex can you please show me some code to use java SDK in ACF? Because I'm struggling to pass the arguments to the java objects.